# In java, How did last ch++ answer ":;"happen?

Tags: java

```java
char ch='A';
System.out.println(ch); //prints A
ch++;
System.out.println(ch); //prints B
ch='0';
System.out.println(ch); //prints 0
ch++;
System.out.println(ch); //prints 1
ch='9';
System.out.println(ch); //prints 9
ch++;
System.out.println(ch); //prints :
```

Why did the `ch++` make the program print a colon after the 9?

Comment: Post your code not a picture

Comment: Again code not a picture and enclose your code in \`\`\`<put your code here\`\`\`.

Comment: [This should explain it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII-Table-wide.svg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ASCII character set `:` comes after `9`, so when you increment you basically go to `:`.

Take a look at this:
[image]

NOTE: Although Java might use unicode instead of ASCII, unicode is built on top of ASCII and decimal values for alphabetical characters and some others are the same.

Comment: Java uses the Unicode character set, not ASCII.

Comment: It does but Unicode is extension of ASCII

Answer (score 1):

Refer to http://asciitable.com/. By calling `ch++`, you increment the character number. ASCII is a system that maps numbers to characters. If you look for the entry for the character 9, you'll see that the character right after it is the colon.

```
57 39 071 &#57 9
58 3A 072 &#58 :
```

Thus if you increment ch, it'll end up as a colon.

Answer (score 1):

While doing `ch++;`, what you are doing is adding the ASCII value of the `ch`, which is `9` in this case. If you look at an ASCII chart, the ASCII value right after a `9` is a `:`, which is what is printed.

The `ch` value of `9` is used from the lines above in the program.